# why accept values but doesn't accept dataframe column : Nan value in dataframe output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I 'am trying to calculate back irradiation and front irradiation on solar pv system in bifacial system ,  so i used pvfactors package in python
this is the link of code used :
https://pythonlang.dev/repo/sunpower-pvfactors/
just I have made some modification into dataframe my modifications are :

```
# Import external libraries
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#define pi as cste
PI=np.pi
#read meteo data
meteo = pd.read_csv('test_BifacialSystem.csv', skiprows=1, header=None, delimiter=';', index_col=0)

#define columns of dataframe 
meteo.columns = ['GHI', 'DHI', 'jour','h1','Time','HSol','AzSol']

#create site system characteristics
meteo['solar_azimuth']= 0
meteo['solar_zenith']= meteo['HSol'] - (PI/2)
meteo['surface_azimuth']=0
meteo['surface_tilt']= 20
meteo['axis_azimuth'] = 0
meteo['dni'] = (meteo['GHI'] - meteo['DHI'])/ np.cos(meteo['solar_zenith'])
meteo['gcr']= 65.1 / 81   #module area / ground area 
meteo['axis_azimuth'] = 180
meteo['pvrow_height']=2.1
meteo['pvrow_width']=6
meteo['n_pvrows']=3
meteo['index_observed_pvrow']=1
meteo['rho_front_pvrow']=0.03
meteo['rho_back_pvrow']=0.05
meteo['horizon_band_angle']=15
meteo['albedo']=0.4

print(meteo)
# Create input data
df_inputs = pd.DataFrame(
    {'solar_zenith': meteo['solar_zenith'],
     'solar_azimuth': meteo['solar_azimuth'],
     'surface_tilt':  meteo['surface_tilt'],
     'surface_azimuth': meteo['surface_azimuth'],
     'dni': meteo['dni'],
     'dhi': meteo['DHI'],
     'albedo': meteo['albedo']}, 
    index= pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', closed='left', freq='1h', tz=None))
#print(df_inputs)


pvarray_parameters = {
    'n_pvrows': 3,            # number of pv rows
    'pvrow_height': 2.1,        # height of pvrows (measured at center / torque tube)
    'pvrow_width': 6,         # width of pvrows
    'axis_azimuth': 0.,       # azimuth angle of rotation axis
    'gcr': 0.8,               # ground coverage ratio
}
```

so when I print df_report : a dataframe with Nan values come :

```
                     total_incident_back  total_absorbed_back
2000-01-01 00:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
2000-01-01 01:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
2000-01-01 02:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
2000-01-01 03:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
2000-01-01 04:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
...                                  ...                  ...
2000-12-31 19:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
2000-12-31 20:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
2000-12-31 21:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
2000-12-31 22:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
2000-12-31 23:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
```

any help please !! thanks in advance

Comment: Reproducible example would be helpful. Some people may help, but just do not have  time to do unnecessary detective work.

Comment: you're right !! but just I want ask why it accept values but doesn't accept dataframe column